# Kendo chart, how to increase size of note icon?

Tags: kendo-dataviz

I am trying to draw a thick x-axis with an arrow head. For the arrow head I am trying to use the notes feature of kendo chart.  The size of arrow head doesn’t change based on the configuration.
Click here to see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RASA/A9axh/18/). Please see below '**size: 16**' has no effect on the graph.

My code below,

```
valueAxis: {
        notes: {
            position: "left",
            line: {
                color: "",
                length: 280

            },
            data: [{
                value: 0,
                icon: {
                    background: "red",
                    type: "triangle",
                   rotation: 90,
                    size: 16
                }
            }],
        },
        labels: {
            template: " #if(value ==0){# #: value # % #}#"
        },
        line: {
            visible: false
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        },
        minorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to position the size outside the brackets

```
icon: {
     background: "red",
     type: "triangle",
      rotation: 90
}
```

**size: 16**